# How can I read this xml?

Tags: php, xml

could you help me?

I need to read this file:

I Tried this way:

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.crossref.org/works/10.18468/pracs.2016v9n3.p99-119/transform/application/vnd.crossref.unixsd+xml');

echo $xml->journal_metadata->full_title;

I don´t know how to get the value of a specific tag.

I need read this:[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OORFs.png)

Comment: _"but it doesn´t work"_ is quite a short description of the specific problem you have....

Comment: and no, this way nobody can help you (exept for doing your work..). Do you have any code you have problems with? What have you tried?

Comment: have you at least googled "xml parser php"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do not go to another site to see what you're asking, and we cannot help you with why code we cannot see is not working for you. See [ask] and [mcve] (and while you're at it [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)), and then come back and [edit] your post to include the relevant details **here**, in your question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you load the file from the distant server :

```
$file = @file_get_contents('http://api.crossref.org/works/10.18468/pracs.2016v9n3.p99-119/transform/application/vnd.crossref.unixsd+xml');
if ($file===FALSE)
{
    die ("error getting the content of the file");
}
```

Then, you parse the xml and extract it into an object using  simplexml :

```
$o= simplexml_load_string ($file);
```

Finally, you move through your object tree until you reach the intended destination

```
echo "<pre>";
$intended_obj = $o->query_result->body->query->doi_record->crossref->journal->journal_article->doi_data;
print_r($intended_obj->resource);
print_r($intended_obj->collection);
echo "</pre>";
```

That should output :

```
   SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => https://periodicos.unifap.br/index.php/pracs/article/view/2791
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [property] => crawler-based
        )
    [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [crawler] => iParadigms
                )
            [resource] => https://periodicos.unifap.br/index.php/pracs/article/viewFile/2791/haliadorav9n3.pdf
        )
)
```

Good luck,